# convert MJD to date java

Tags: java, datetime, julian-date

I ma trying to understand following paragraph:

**start_time:** This 40-bit field contains the start time of the event in Universal Time, Co-ordinated (UTC) and Modified Julian Date (MJD). This field is coded as 16 bits giving the 16 LSBs of MJD followed by 24 bits coded as 6 digits in 4-bit Binary Coded Decimal (BCD). If the start time is undefined (e.g. for an event in a NVOD reference service) all bits of the field are set to "1".

**Example 1:** `93/10/13 12:45:00` is coded as "`0xC079124500`".

I want to convert 40-bit to date and time in java without using third party library.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working.

From 40 bits, 16 msb bits represents MJD. Remaining 24 bits represent time in BCD coded as `HHMMSS`.

For example `0xC079` in question represents MJD, that is `49273` in decimal.

To convert MJD to date, convert MJD in decimal (above converted to 49273), then:

To find Y, M, D from MJD:

```
Y' = int [(MJD - 15078.2) / 365.25]
M' = int { [MJD - 14956.1 - int (Y' * 365.25) ] / 30.6001 }
D = MJD - 14956 - int (Y' * 365.25) - int (M' * 30.6001 )

If M' = 14 or M' = 15, then K = 1; else K = 0

Y = Y' + K

M = M' - 1 - K * 12
```

Where

`MJD` Modified Julian Date

`Y` Year from 1900 (e.g. for 2003, Y = 103)

`M` Month from January (= 1) to December (= 12)

`D` Day of month from 1 to 31

`K` ,`M'`, `Y'` Intermediate variables

`*` Multiplication

`int` Integer part, ignoring remainder

Comment: Where do the values `15078.2`, `14956.1` and `30.6001` come from? Seeing as you're dropping remainders, how far have you gone testing this to ensure that some dates won't actually end up 1 lower or higher than expected? And when you apply `int` are you _literally_ ignoring remainder, because some `int` casts could perform unwanted rounding?